# How can i Skip fragments when going D to A on backpressed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

Hey I am working on an application where I m using 6 fragments now when on the back button I want to skip all the other fragments like when I am on the 6th fragment(the last fragment) and the user presses the back button I want to go to fragment one directly without going through the other fragments
like 6->1.
I am new to android please guide me on how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the *Navigation* library, when you create an `action` that navigates you to *Fragment 6*, [you can use the `popUpTo` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) to clear the backstack up to *Fragment 1*. That way, when you go to *6*, hitting the back button will take you to *1*.

---

If you're [doing things by hand with `FragmentTransaction`s](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform), when you `add` *Fragment 1* to the container you should call `addToBackStack("Fragment 1")` (or some other name to represent that state, "top level" or something). Then you can use [`popBackStack("Fragment 1", 0)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack(java.lang.String,int)) to undo any transactions that happened after that, basically walking back to where you displayed *Fragment 1*.

If you're doing that, you'll have to intercept the back button handling in *Fragment 6* so you can call that `popBackStack` method, instead of just letting it pop the top state off. [Here's how you're meant to handle that](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back).

Another thing you could try is doing the `popBackStack` call inside the `FragmentTransaction` that goes from *5* to *6*, popping everything back to *1* before you `add` *Fragment 6* and then call `addToBackStack` (so you're basically backtracking to *1*, then adding one step that takes you to *6*, so there's only one step back to *1*). I haven't tried that, but it should work I think!

It's honestly a lot easier to just use the *Navigation* library, it takes care of this kind of wrangling for you

Comment: thank you for your great help I am using the navigation library and defined the popUpTo attribute in my nav_graph's fragment section but still when on the back press it is not working ???

Comment: @VivekMFauzdar you set it on the `action` that *takes you to* Fragment 6. That way, when you arrive at 6, the backstack has already been cleared so the back button will take you to 1. If there's more than one `action` that takes you to Fragment 6, you'll need to set `popUpTo` on all of them